# Object has the same property multiple times

Tags: c#

When I inspect my object in the debugger, it has 3 different entries for the property `VgnItm`.

[image]

How does an object get multiple of a property?

Here is the class with multiple of `VgnItm` property:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Nest;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Vepo.Domain
{
    [Serializable]
    public class VgnItmEstDto : CreatedBySomeoneDto
    {
        [Required]
        public int VgnItmId { get; set; }
        public int? EstId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int NotInEstCount { get; set; } = 0;
        [Required]
        public int InEstCount { get; set; } = 0;
        public double? Price { get; set; }
        [Object]
        public EstDto Est { get; set; }
        public VgnItmDto VgnItm { get; set; }
        public string Discriminator { get; set; }
    }

    public class VgnItmEstDto<TVgnItmDto> : VgnItmEstDto
        where TVgnItmDto : VgnItmDto
    {
        public new TVgnItmDto VgnItm { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: A likely reason for the duplicate property names is that you redeclared the property in an inherited class, creating another property that has the same name.

Comment: Don't you know the [new modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @PalleDue No, this is a completely different question. That is just a plain old null reference exception question.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain So there is no place on the internet for a question about a C# object having the same property multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hiding a property with the `new` keyword doesn't mean that that property ceases to exist. Of course there are two properties with the same name: the one you declared and the one you hid. If you want to hide the base property with one of a more specific type then you would usually implement the getter and setter to pass through to the base property:

```cs
public class VgnItmEstDto<TVgnItmDto> : VgnItmEstDto
    where TVgnItmDto : VgnItmDto
{
    public new TVgnItmDto VgnItm
    {
        get => base.VgnItm;
        set => base.VgnItm = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: redirecting the new property to the hidden one won't change anything on serialization. The property will still occur twice.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain, it was my impression that the `NullReferenceException` was because the base property was not being set when setting the new property. This will address that.